# How to limit connections to a port and redirect other requests to another port?

Tags: django, ubuntu, server, iptables

I would like to limit the number of connections to my server to X. This can be done by

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ABCD -m connlimit --connlimit-above X --connlimit-mask 0 -j DROP
```

Also, I would like to redirect the dropped requests to another port, say PQRS. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect them to other chain and then handle it on other chain.

Create a custom chain:

```
iptables -N custom_chain
```

Then redirect the traffic to the new chain:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ABCD -m connlimit --connlimit-above X --connlimit-mask 0 -j custom_chain
```

Finally handle the traffic on your new custom chain to redirect traffic to desired XXXX port:

```
iptables -t nat -A custom_chain -p tcp --dport ABCD -j REDIRECT --to-port XXXX
```

Comment: I am getting an error when running the third command. 

iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Comment: I think the problem is the new chain wasn't created as "-t nat" chain. Maybe the first command should be `iptables -N custom_chain -t nat`. Anyway, I'm only trying to point you on the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it is not working. Perhaps I am missing something that you assume that I would know.